# Raspberry Pi Air gap

Tags: security, communication

can i Use a Raspberry Pi as a [air gap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_gap_%28networking%29) set up?

I have heard that some people will use a separate computer for decrypting messages. When they revive a message they will put it on a thumb drive and then they will carry it to a separate computer that is not connected to the internet, they will then decrypt the message.

Would the Raspberry Pi be a good computer for the decrypting of messages encrypted with RSA?

Comment: Why not. RSA is not that CPU intensive. Nothing the Pi can't handle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a Certification Authority set up in a Raspberry Pi, with an Air Gap model, running xCA, which runs great on the Pi, by the way.

It can do even asymetric cryptography without problems, but I would say you have to measure the amount of cryptography and the response time you need, given that very large amounts of data can take a while to process. I don't think that will be a problem, though.

As for scruss answer about the Pi not handling USB insertion/removal right, considering I don't think you will be doing that many times per hour, so, if a reboot is acceptable (as it is in my case) it doesn't turn out to be a real issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say no.

Not because of lack of computing power — Gerben's comment is dead right — but because the Raspberry Pi doesn't handle external USB insertion/removal well. Some models will reboot on inserting a USB device.

Comment: Doesn't an externally powered USB hub more or less solve that issue?

Comment: Not entirely reliably, in my experience.

Comment: This is caused by brownouts. You need a better power supply. IIRC earlier Pis also had issues with high resistance fuses, but that’s been fixed.

Comment: @Navin - this is a very old question, and your comment couldn't have worked when it was asked